# How to encrypt a variable value in SSIS

Tags: sql, encryption, ssis, passwords, ssis-2012

I am developing a routine that imports data from a 3rd party SFTP server. This server uses WinSCP to create the SFTP Connection and uses a SSH Private Key for the connection rather than a username and password. So I create my connection as below in a script task:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = ftpSite,
            UserName = username,
            Password = password,
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = sshKey,
            SshPrivateKeyPassphrase = "mypassword",
            SshPrivateKeyPath = @"C:\path\to\private.ppk"
        };
```

I'm happy enough storing the Private Key Path in a database table (which contains my connectoin settings) but I want to store the SshPrivateKeyPassphrase somehwere that is encrypted. I was initially thinking can I create an Encrypted Variable, so if you look at the xml of the package, it won't expose the password directly, but I can reference the variable in code to pass the password to the connection.

I was also looking at creating a dummy Connection and see if I can refer to the connection and get the password in the code, but it seems a bit of a fudge.

The solution the package is in is passworded, i'm just trying to cover all bases, so if someone gets access to the package who shouldn't, they won't get the private key passphrase as that would cause us all sorts of issues.

Comment: Since you tagged with 2012, my immediate thought was a package level parameter as you can mark that as sensitive, but they're readonly during package execution. You could possibly fake it by having a dedicated package that assumes it's receiving the correct value and then have a master package read in the value and pass it to the child.

Comment: I'll play about with that, but again it seems a bit of a fudge. I thought that there may have been a way internally within SSIS to encrypt a value of a variable easily, but it seems I may need to rethink my process.